# Destroying service before removing the relation causes both services to hang at dying

Tags: mysql, juju, maas, wordpress

I deployed wordpress and mysql and add relation between wordpress and mysql. I try to destroy wordpress before removing the relation between wordpress and mysql.

Now, both services are hanging at dying. What should I do? is there any way to manually delete the service cleanly?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Here is the output from juju status mysql:

```
controller:~$ juju status mysql
environment: maas
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.16.6.1
    dns-name: node-1.master
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-345fea0a-9f84-11e3-88be-525400429c50/
    series: precise
services:
  mysql:
    charm: cs:precise/mysql-35
    exposed: false
    life: dying
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mysql
      db:
      - wordpress
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.16.6.1
        life: dying
        machine: "0"
        public-address: node-1.master
```

Part of the output from juju status (yes, it ends at db: - mysql)

```
  wordpress:
    charm: cs:precise/wordpress-21
    exposed: false
    life: dying
    relations:
      db:
      - mysql
```

Log related(juju debug-log):

```
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju runner.go:253 worker: start "uniter"
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:83 unit "mysql/0" started
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:421 ModeInit starting
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:29 updating unit addresses
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:454 unit is dying
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:504 charm check         skipped, unit is dying
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:54 reconciling relation state
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:322 got service change
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:517 joining relation "wordpress:db mysql:db"
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:504 charm check     skipped, unit is dying
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:338 got relations change
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:314 got unit change
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:543 joined relation "wordpress:db mysql:db"
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter modes.go:423 ModeInit exiting
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:421 ModeContinue starting
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:67 loading uniter state
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:108 found uncommitted     "config-changed" hook
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:363 committing "config-    changed" hook
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:330 got config change
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:334 preparing new config event
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 ERROR juju git.go:188 worker/uniter/charm: git command failed: exit status 128
node-1:ath: /var/lib/juju/agents/unit-mysql-0/charm
node-1:rgs: []string{"commit", "--allow-empty", "-m", "Completed \"config-changed\" hook."}
node-1:rror: object file .git/objects/d4/7f136f29e2319929b668b4e7917dca934b462f is     empty
node-1:atal: loose object d47f136f29e2319929b668b4e7917dca934b462f (stored in .git/objects/d4/7f136f29e2319929b668b4e7917dca934b462f) is corrupt
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter modes.go:423 ModeContinue exiting
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:105 unit "mysql/0"     shutting down: ModeContinue: git commit failed: exit status 128
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:117 tomb: dying
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 ERROR juju runner.go:211 worker: exited "uniter":     ModeContinue: git commit failed: exit status 128
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:12 INFO juju runner.go:245 worker: restarting "uniter" in 3s
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju runner.go:253 worker: start "uniter"
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:83 unit "mysql/0" started
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:421 ModeInit starting
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:29 updating unit addresses
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:454 unit is dying
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:504 charm check     skipped, unit is dying
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:54 reconciling relation     state
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:322 got service     change
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:517 joining relation     "wordpress:db mysql:db"
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:504 charm check     skipped, unit is dying
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:338 got relations     change
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:314 got unit     change
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:543 joined relation     "wordpress:db mysql:db"
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter modes.go:423 ModeInit exiting
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:421 ModeContinue starting
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:67 loading uniter state
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:108 found uncommitted     "config-changed" hook
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:363 committing "config-    changed" hook
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:330 got config     change
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:334 preparing new     config event
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 ERROR juju git.go:188 worker/uniter/charm: git command     failed: exit status 128
node-1:ath: /var/lib/juju/agents/unit-mysql-0/charm
node-1:rgs: []string{"commit", "--allow-empty", "-m", "Completed \"config-changed\"     hook."}
node-1:rror: object file .git/objects/d4/7f136f29e2319929b668b4e7917dca934b462f is empty
node-1:atal: loose object d47f136f29e2319929b668b4e7917dca934b462f (stored in     .git/objects/d4/7f136f29e2319929b668b4e7917dca934b462f) is corrupt
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter modes.go:423 ModeContinue exiting
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:105 unit "mysql/0"     shutting down: ModeContinue: git commit failed: exit status 128
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:117 tomb: dying
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 ERROR juju runner.go:211 worker: exited "uniter":     ModeContinue: git commit failed: exit status 128
node-1:014-03-03 19:32:15 INFO juju runner.go:245 worker: restarting "uniter" in 3s
```

Please let me know if there is an easy fix? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% positive this works with MAAS - but I know this method works with other providers. When I want to destroy a service and its "stuck" in a dying state, using your wordpress deployment as an example:

```
juju resolve wordpress/0
```

now if that fails to help the situation, ergo, it continues to go from hook to hook in an error state, I will destroy the machine with extreme predjudice. (note, this yields an unrecoverable machine, and should be treated with caution, as you would any rm -rf operation - this WILL destroy the machine in question)

Obtain the machine id from the command `juju status` - then:

```
 juju destroy-machine --force <machine_id>
```

If this continues to leave the mysql service in a state of distress, you can resolve it manually following the above workflow:

```
juju resolve mysql/0
```

if all else fails, and you dont care about the data

```
juju destroy-machine --force <machine_id>
```

In relation to the log output - know that there is an effort to move juju away from using git, so stray issues like this do not crop up for end users. I don't have an ETA on when this feature will land but its WIP at current.

Comment: Thank you lazyPower. I believe I have tried `juju resolved wordpress/0` but it doesn't work neither does `destroy-machine`. It gave me error message like: mysql service is still on. I don't remember clearly, but even the `--force` option cannot terminate a machine with service on it? If the machine is pending with error or have no response, the `--force` does work.  I finally destroy the environment and bootstrap again. I thought there might have some other issues with the node instead of juju.

Comment: @lazyPower This is real.  It is also an issue if you have an error in your relation joined hook.  Service goes into error state, and you *can't* kill it, except by killing the machines.  This is a PITA when developing hooks, as I have need to bootstrap every iteration.  Now I'm not deploying to the bootstrap/juju-gui server, so it goes faster.